# Uploading multiple files in Django 2.0

Tags: django, python-3.x

I really spend the two last days on searching how to upload single file in Django 2.0 and after achieving it, here I'm in front of "Uploading Multiple Files", the documentation isn't enough, I searched many time without any result.
Here is my code:

models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Image(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    image = models.ImageField()

    def __str__(self):
        return "{0} => {1}".format(self.id, self.title)
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from . import models

class Image_Form(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Image
        fields = "__all__"
        widgets = {
            "title": forms.TextInput(
                    attrs={
                        "required": "True",
                        "autofocus": "True",
                    }
                ),
            "image": forms.FileInput(attrs={'multiple': True}),
        }
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from . import models, forms
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView

def index(request):
    all_images = models.Image.objects.all()
    image_form = forms.Image_Form()
    upload_files = Upload_Files()

    dico = {
        "images_key": all_images,
        "form_key": image_form,
        "upload_key": upload_files,
    }
    return render(request, "index.html", dico)

def media_upload(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        upload_files = Upload_Files()
        upload_files.post(request)
    else:
        return redirect("index")

class Upload_Files(FormView):
    form_class = forms.Image_Form
    template_name="index.html"
    success_url = '/index/'

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)
        files = request.FILES.getlist('image')
        if form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <title>index page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="POST" action="{% url 'media_upload' %}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
            <p>{{ form_key.title }}</p>
            <p>{{ form_key.image }}</p>
            <p><input type="submit" value="Save"/></p>
        </form>
        <hr/><hr/>
        {% for i in images_key %}
            <p>{{ i.title }}</p>
            <p><img src="{{ i.image.url }}"/></p>
            <hr/>
        {% endfor %}
    </body>
</html>
```

I appreciate your help. Thank you :) :)

Comment: You've shared the code but you've not told us what isn't working? What problem/error are you faced with?

Comment: the problem is in the views.py file, I don't know how to save multiple files in the DB

Comment: This is not the direct answer to the OP but IMO, you should upload the files in independent API calls. And no point in reinventing the wheel. Have a look at FineUploader and let that package handle the multiple uploads using your single upload command

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in `index.html`: you should delete `action="{% url 'media_upload' %}"`, i.e. change

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'media_upload' %}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

to

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```